# replace image with drag drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I've gotten help from several on this site developing a drag/drop educational game where students drag images into the proper order.  I was able to accomplish my goals in a Winform with Visual Basic.  Now I'm trying to do the same in html.  Using the three functions below, I'm able to drag and drop an image from one div into another empty div.  But it doesn't work if I attempt to drop an image into a div that already contains an image.  I did see a response in StackOverflow about using this line  "ev.target.removeChild(ev.target.childNodes[0]" in the drop function.  But this just creates an error "Argument 1 of Node.removeChild is not an object."  Thanks for  your help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5
{float:left; width:100px; height:35px; margin:10px;padding:10px;border:1px                     solid #0066ff;}
#btn1
{float:left; width: 120px; height: 40px; margin: 125px; }
</style>
<script>

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    //ev.target.removeChild(ev.target.childNodes[0]); //This line created an     error
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img       src='Images/grass(3).jpg' draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1"     width="88" height="31"> </div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img    src="Images/sun.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="88" height="31"> </div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do two things: One, provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not a brief code snippet, unless the MCVE would be really long. Two, only ask one question per question -- getting one image to replace the other is (or seems to be at least) a separate question to getting them to swap.

Comment: Make sure you're dropping in on the div and not the image.

Comment: Musa, you are right . . . if I increase the size of the div then I can drag a second image in there.  This could help if I did some work-arounds.  My preference would be to remove (and copy) the image in the drop zone just before I drop the new image in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error plus internet searches, I finally came up with an answer to my own question.  The essence of my question was that I could not drag and drop one image on to another.  Typically the dragged image would disappear.  What I really wanted to do was "swap" two images, and drop image A on to image B and then have image B show up where image A was.

I found a tutorial sample by Sue Smith at the following web site:

http://www.webdesign.org/how-to-create-an-html5-drag-and-drop-component.22289.html

In this sample she shows how to set up 6 divs, each with an inner div with a text string in each inner div (typically one word.)  In her sample it was very easy to drag and "swap" one word with another.  But if you put an image in the div, it would no longer work.

So what I did was create an ID for each inner div.  Then I assigned a background image for each inner div as well as removed the text.  After experimenting with Sue Smith's code, I was finally able to accomplish the replacing and swapping of inner divs (with their associated background picture.)  The end result is that it looks as if you are just dragging, dropping and swapping images.  This worked fine in both Chrome and Firefox.  For some reason it did not work in IE ver 11. You can see the modified code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html> 
    <head>
         <style type="text/css">
         .mover {
             width:200px; height:170px; line-height:4em; margin:10px;                                                padding:5px; float:left; 
             border:1px dotted #333333; text-align:center;  
             } 
             #boxA{
                background-image: url(images/coyote.jpg)
             }
             #boxB{
                background-image: url(images/black_bear.jpg)
             }
             #boxC{
                background-image: url(images/grass.jpg)
             }
             #boxD{
                background-image: url(images/rabbits.jpg)
             }
             #boxE{
                background-image: url(images/sun.jpg)
              }
          </style>
          <script type="text/javascript">
               function dragWord(dragEvent){
                  dragEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Id",    dragEvent.target.id+"|"+dragEvent.target.parentNode.id);
                 }                   
               function dropWord(dropEvent){ 
                var dropData = dropEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Id");
                dropItems = dropData.split("|"); 
                var prevElem = document.getElementById(dropItems[1]); 
                prevElem.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].id =      dropEvent.target.id;              
                dropEvent.target.id = dropItems[0]; 
                dropEvent.preventDefault(); 
                } 
                </script> 
                </head> 
                <body> <div><em>Drag and drop the pictures in order to show      how energy moves through a food chain.</em></div> 
                    <div id="box1" ondragover="event.preventDefault()"      ondrop="dropWord(event)" > 
                    <div class="mover" id="boxA" draggable="true"      ondragstart="dragWord(event)" ></div> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="box2" ondragover="event.preventDefault()"     ondrop="dropWord(event)"> 
                    <div class="mover" id="boxB" draggable="true"      ondragstart="dragWord(event)"></div> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="box3" ondragover="event.preventDefault()"      ondrop="dropWord(event)"> 
                    <div class="mover" id="boxC" draggable="true"      ondragstart="dragWord(event)"></div> 
                    </div> 
                    <div id="box4" ondragover="event.preventDefault()"      ondrop="dropWord(event)"> 
                    <div class="mover" id="boxD" draggable="true"      ondragstart="dragWord(event)"></div> 
                    </div> 
                    <div id="box5" ondragover="event.preventDefault()"      ondrop="dropWord(event)"> 
                    <div class="mover" id="boxE" draggable="true"     ondragstart="dragWord(event)"></div> 
                    </div>                                      
            </body> 
            </html>
```